# Third derivative of a multidimensional function

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $ f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z)\mapsto \sin(x)\cdot \cos(y)\cdot e^z $. I want to calculate the third derivative $ D^3f((0,0,0))((x,y,z),(x,y,z),(x,y,z)) $ of $ f $ at $ (0,0,0) $. At first I was able to calculate the first two derivatives of $ f $ at $ (0,0,0) $:

$$ \begin{align}Df((0,0,0))((x,y,z))&=\underbrace{(1,0,0)}_{\text{Jacobian-Matrix}}\cdot (x,y,z)^T=x\\D^2f((0,0,0))((x,y,z),(x,y,z))&=(x,y,z)\cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{Hessian-Matrix}}\cdot (x,y,z)^T=2\cdot x\cdot z \end{align} $$

But how do I calculate the third derivative?

Comment: It is a rank 3 tensor. You compute it the same way you computed the other derivatives, you just can't write it on a piece of paper in one go.

Comment: You mean in theory I would have to calculate all third partial derivatives of f?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You could also do series multiplication and collect all of the terms of order 3.